# Why doesn't the INTERFACE_SYSTEM_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES target property add include directories to the target?

Tags: cmake

I have a slightly unusual setup where I need some header-only library to be included in a project. The headers are located within a sub-folder of the project (e.g. `mylib/include`). Now I wanted to create an imported interface library out of it - I cannot create a static, shared etc. library, since it is header only it needs to be an interface library.
But I need to specify the include directory for all consumers of the library. According to the documentation I can do this by specifying the `INTERFACE_*` and `IMPORTED_*` target properties. Since I want the library to be used as a 3rd party library, by using system includes. Therefore I specified:

```
add_library (mylib INTERFACE IMPORTED GLOBAL)
set_target_properties (mylib PROPERTIES
    INTERFACE_SYSTEM_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/mylib/include
)
```

Somewhere else in the project I do:

```
target_link_libraries (runner PRIVATE mylib)
```

This is also accepted by CMake during configuration. But when I try to build the project, the header files of `mylib` cannot be found - CMake does not append `mylib/include` to the include directories of `runner`.

In the generated `compile_commands.json` the folder of `mylib/include` is not present.
Am I missing something? Do I need to specify something else?

Comment: Unrelated: Be aware that `CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR` may not be the correct way to refer to a location relative to the file containing the code. If this variable is read in a cmake script (e.g. when doing `find_package`) `CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR` still refers to the directory containing the last `CMakeLists.txt` file entered. Usually `CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR` is used in find script or cmake package configuration script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is [INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES.html) property which contains include directories for use in the consumers of a library. The property [INTERFACE_SYSTEM_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/INTERFACE_SYSTEM_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES.html) is used only for **mark** some of include directories as system:

> Projects may also get and set the property directly, but must be aware that adding directories to this property does not make those directories used during compilation. Adding directories to this property marks directories as system directories which otherwise would be used in a non-system manner.

So, you may fill both of `INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES` and `INTERFACE_SYSTEM_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES` properties ... or fill only the first one: all include directories of an **IMPORTED** target are treated as system by **default**:

```cmake
add_library (mylib INTERFACE IMPORTED GLOBAL)
set_target_properties (mylib PROPERTIES
    INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/mylib/include
)
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply! This makes a lot of sense - I wasn't aware of this difference between those properties but thinking about it makes sense - or lets me ask what `INTERFACE_SYSTEM_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES` is for anyway. If system is the default, this one seems useless.

Comment: "system" is default only for IMPORTED libraries. Other libraries - normal or INTERFACE - doesn't have such default. Note, that since CMake 3.11 it is allowed to call `target_include_directories` even for IMPORTED libraries, so you may use this command instead of working with the properties directly. E.g. `target_include_directories(mylib SYSTEM INTERFACE mylib/include)` would automatically convert relative path to absolute and fill both `INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES` and `INTERFACE_SYSTEM_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES` properties.